# How can I extract agent-set by using RNetLogo?

Tags: r, netlogo, agentset

I have trouble getting agent-sets in R using RNetLogo package

```
NLCommand("setup")
who <- list()
who[[i]] <- NLGetAgentSet(c("who","xcor","ycor"), "turtles")
```

Is there something wrong in using NLGetAgetSet function? I need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue should be fixed in the version 1.0-4 of RNetLogo available from rforge.

Use

install.packages("RNetLogo", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")

to install it from rforge (instead from CRAN).

If you confirm that the issue is fixed I will update the CRAN package from 1.0-3 to 1.0-4.

Comment: Incredibly this works, too!!! I could have save 40 something hours if I knew this in advance. Thank you very much for not skipping this question~!!!:) Wait, come to think of it, aren't you a designer of this packages? My pleasure meeting you

Answer (score 1):

The `NLGetAgentSet` and `NLGetPatches` are not working with NetLogo 6.0.
(I think this is related to https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/transition.html#v60).

Luckily, these functions are only wrappers for `NLReport`. So you can get the agents with `NLReport` instead. For example:

```
vars <- c("who", "xcor", "ycor")
agents <- "turtles"

reporters <- sprintf("map [x -> [%s] of x ] sort %s", vars, agents)
nlogo_ret <- RNetLogo::NLReport(reporters)
df1 <- data.frame(nlogo_ret, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df1) <- vars
```

Comment: Wow~!! You really solve my problem~!!! Thank you very much~!! If I could have one more question, what is "::" in the "RNetLogo::NLReport(reporters)" means anyway...?)

Comment: Oh, you can just skip the package name if the package is previously loaded by `library(RNetLogo)`.